# Why Are Android Studio Menus Not Working?

Tags: android-studio

I have been using Android Studio for years. Very shortly after upgrading to Android Studio 3.5, the menu options have stopped working. I mean, anything under File, Edit .. all the way to Help. By "stopped working", I mean, I can use the mouse to select, and then .. nothing happens. A colleague suggested to invalidate caches. But invalidate caches itself is under the File menu, so nothing happens when it is selected.
[image: Example of menu selection]

Any ideas? Quitting and starting android studio didn't work. Rebooting didn't work. Changing the java version used to run Android Studio didn't work (it is set to be the same one that gradle is using). Even downloading and installing a fresh copy of Android Studio 3.5 didn't work -> from this, I suspect the problem is a settings problem, but WHICH settings got somehow corrupted? and that survives *even with a fresh installation of Android Studio*?

[image: Normal way to select Find-in-path]
To find-in-path, the menu option doesn't work, whereas I can directly use the keyboard shortcut ⇧⌘F and it brings up the find window.

Am running on MacOS Mojave. Java home is /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_221.jdk/Contents/Home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, Android Studio 4.0 came along, and we installed the patch to upgrade to it, and the mysterious problem went away, presumably as a result of the upgrade.